# Chronologically first "hardboiled" SF or F

Tags: history-of

First, a bit of definitions. "[Hardboiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardboiled)" was codified by Chandler, so we don't have to look earlier than that (even if I wouldn't be surprised to find proto-hardboiled before that, just as SF existed before the term). Crime novel and even Noir is far too wide, but we can as well take Robert Rankin's Lazlo Woodbine as the ultimate hardboiled-redux to check off. Or peruse TV Tropes :-)

I retain the right to reject hardboiled offers on flimsy grounds (Random examples how I see it: Artemis Fowl is too for-children, Harry Dresden is not cynical enough, but Miller from The Expanse fits big time), but if already the blurb says "Chandler parody" you're good.

I googled around a bit, there are numerous reading suggestions, but as I said at the moment I'm interested who came up with the idea first. You may split into F and SF.

(Background: Some writer in his afterword boldly asserted he invented the hard-boiled quarter-ork. That's so specific he may be right :-)

Comment: If you read through some of the classic '40s and '50s SF pulps you'll find a fair number of stories of this type, though nothing pops to mind right now.  (Less *Astounding* and more *Weird Tales* or *Famous Fantastic Mysteries*.)

Comment: There are a bunch of Raymond Chandler take-offs from the 80's and 90's, such as a Glen Cook's. [Garrett, P. I.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garrett_P.I.) fantasy detective series or Mel Gilden's _[Surfing Samurai Robots](https://books.google.com/books/about/Surfing_Samurai_Robots.html)_ but those are probably not the first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the "hardboiled" genre, hope this is hardboiled enough.

**1953:** ["Stop, Look and Dig"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?536917), a short story by [George O. Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_O._Smith), first published in [*Space Science Fiction*, March 1953](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?181985+c), available at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/19963).

> Someone behind me in the dark was toting a needle-ray. The impression came through so strong that I could almost read the filed-off serial number of the thing, but the guy himself I couldn't dig at all. I stopped to look back but the only sign of life I could see was the fast flick of taxicab lights as they crossed an intersection about a half mile back. I stepped into a doorway so that I could think and stay out of the line of fire at the same time.
>
> The impression of the needle-ray did not get any stronger, and that tipped me off. The bird was following me. He was no peace-loving citizen because honest men do not cart weapons with the serial numbers filed off. Therefore the character tailing me was a hot papa with a burner charge labelled "Steve Hammond" in his needler.
>
> I concentrated, but the only impression I could get would have specified ninety-eight men out of a hundred anywhere. He was shorter than my six-feet-two and lighter than my one-ninety. I could guess that he was better looking. I'd had my features arranged by a blocked drop kick the year before the National Football League ruled the Rhine Institute out because of our use of mentals and perceptives. I gave up trying--I wanted details and not an overall picture of a hotbird carrying a burner.
>
> I wondered if I could make a run for it.
>
> I let my sense of perception dig the street ahead, casing every bump and irregularity. I passed places where I could zig out to take cover in front of telephone poles, and other places where I could zag in to take cover beyond front steps and the like. I let my perception run up the block and by the time I got to the end of my range, I knew that block just as well as if I'd made a practise run in the daytime.
>
> At this point I got a shock. The hot papa was coming up the sidewalk hell bent for destruction. He was a mental sensitive, and he had been following my thoughts while my sense of perception made its trial run up the street. He was running like the devil to catch up with my mind and burn it down per schedule. It must have come as quite a shock to him when he realized that while the mind he was reading was running like hell up the street, the hard old body was standing in the doorway waiting for him.
>
> I dove out of my hiding place as he came close. I wanted to tackle him hard and ask some pointed questions. He saw me as I saw him skidding to an unbalanced stop, and there was the dull glint of metal in his right hand. His needle-ray came swinging up and I went for my armpit. I found time to curse my own stupidity for not having hardware in my own fist at the moment. But then I had my rod in my fist. I felt the hot scorch of the needle going off just over my shoulder, and then came the godawful racket of my ancient forty-five. The big slug caught him high in the belly and tossed him back. It folded him over and dropped him in the gutter while the echoes of my cannon were still racketing back and forth up and down the quiet street.

Comment: That's pretty hard-boiled. :)

Comment: I have read enough "hardboiled" (OK, enough "hardboiled" parodies :-) to instantly accept this answer... (even if someone might underbid it, but I conclude that a genre gets parodied as soon as it gets codified).

Comment: The march timing is intriguing considering the Spencer's Answer's source specifies a march 14th date of Chandler's letter. When in March was this published?

Comment: @KareemElashmawy Considering the relative delay in publication of a magazine vs. the fact that one puts the current date when writing a letter, it’s very likely that “Stop, Look, and Dig” was _written_ first, anyway.

Comment: I am under the impression that the dates on magazines are the dates to take them off the newstands to make room for the next issue.  In which case Chandler could have read this story before writting his letter - even though he hated science fictionand probably wouldn't have read it.

Comment: @KareemElashmawy A magazine with a March 1953 cover date would surely have been on sale in Febrary (maybe earlier), and the manuscripts for that issue would have been in the editor's hands in 1952. As for Chandler's piece, there is no indication that it was published at all, before being published in that 2006 blog. So there is no question about which one was published first.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest maybe Chandler himself.

Raymond Chandler famously hated SF and there's a March 14, 1953 letter of his (to his agent) containing a ridiculous hardboiled SF parody.

Chandler scholar Chris Routledge shows the text in his 2006 blog article "[Raymond Chandler Invented Google](https://chrisroutledge.co.uk/2006/06/28/raymond-chandler/)":

> Did you ever read what they call Science Fiction? It’s a scream. It’s written like this:

> > I checked out with K19 on Adabaran III, and stepped out through the crummaliote hatch on my 22 Model Sirus Hardtop. I cocked the timeprojector in secondary and waded through the bright blue manda grass. My breath froze into pink pretzels. I flicked on the heat bars and the Bryllis ran swiftly on five legs, using the other two to send out crylon vibrations. The pressure was almost unbearable, but I caught the range on my wrist computer through the transparent cysicites. I pressed the trigger. The thin violet glow was ice-cold against the rust-colored mountains. The Bryllis shrank to half an inch long and I worked fast stepping on them with the poltex. But it wasn’t enough. The sudden brightness swung me round and the Fourth Moon had already risen. I had exactly four seconds to hot up the disintegrator and Google had told me it wasn’t enough.

Ridiculous, but definitely in the Chandler style.

Comment: They had Google back then? Wow.

Comment: @Adamant No, that's just one of Chandler's nonsense words.  It was actually invented by a guy named [Terry Google](https://youtu.be/nKOcrH_PyU0) back in the 1970s.

Comment: @Spencer Using it that way is an amazing accidental piece of future-prediction, though... Maybe even more than the Simpsons predicting Trump as President.

Comment: This blurb includes a "timeprojector" so uh...

Comment: The source for this answer specified a March 14th 1953 date for the letter. The currently accepted answer also specifies a March 1953 publication date. Was this letter written in response to that publication?

Comment: @terdon It's a joke...The Terry Google bit starts around 5:55 if you only care about that particular joke.

Comment: @KareemElashmawy I strongly doubt it.  It was a letter to his agent, and he certainly wouldn't have read the story to respond to it.

Comment: @Spencer oh man... That whooshing sound you may have heard was the joke going waaaaay over my head. Sorry about that!